# NSButton catch a mouse click event

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, button, mouse

I have the code

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


@interface MyButton : NSButton
{

}

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent;

@end

#import "ContextMenuButton.h"


@implementation MyButton

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent;
{
    // ...
}
```

According to the [NSControl Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) `mouseDown` informs the receiver that the user has pressed the left mouse button.

How could I catch right and others mouse button clicks?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the final task, but to define a new button type it's better to subclass the NSButtonCell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSControl` derives, indirectly, from `NSResponder`, and that has methods `mouseDown:`, `rightMouseDown:` and `otherMouseDown:`, all three taking an `NSEvent*` as parameter.

Comment: Thanks. More exactly is the `NSView` class has method `- (void)rightMouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent` is all I need.

Answer (score 0):

`NSButton` responds only on the left button click. Anyway take a look at [NSEvent type](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSEvent/type). It determines a lot of info about event including wich button was pressed.